# Play GIF "onmouseover", but play only once

Tags: html, css

I have a GIF on my website, and I want it to only play when you hover over it, but only play once. So I don't want the user to be able to trigger the event again unless they refresh the page. Anyone know how to do this?

What I have so far is a static image (first frame of the gif) and on mouseover, it changes to a gif which doesn't loop. If I put my mouse over it again, it will repeat the animation, which is what I don't want.

HTML

```
<img class="footer" src="images/website footer static.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/website footer.gif';"
```

CSS

```
.footer {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
top:10px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); }
```

Comment: One way to do this is removing the onmouseover event from the image element after it has triggered.

Comment: Ok, do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done by moving your JavaScript into a function and adding `removeAttribute('onmouseover')` after it changes the `src`.  Since I don't have your images, I just used the first two that popped up on Google:

```js
function playGIF(elm) {
    elm.src = 'http://www.image-mapper.com/photos/original/missing.png?1263880893';
    elm.removeAttribute('onmouseover');
}
```

```css
.footer {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<img class="footer" src="http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg" onmouseover="playGIF(this);" />
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavpx438/

If you watch the code for the `img` as rendered in Developer Tools, you'll notice that before you move the mouse over the image, the `onmouseover` attribute is present, but the moment you move over it, the image changes followed immediately by the removal of the `onmouseover` attribute for the `img` tag.  This will prevent the image from being reloaded on subsequent mouse overs.

I hope this helps. ^^

**Edit**

Since it seems your "answer-question" and my response comment were removed, I'll add my explanation of it here.

You had asked about using only HTML/CSS.  Though we an do mouseover effects using the pseudo `:hover`, it will revert the display to its original state without the change being made to stick.  The only method of changing the rendered code, which is what you need to do, for a permanent change is through scripting.

That is simply how the languages work.  HTML5 has great improved upon what we can do, but it's still a fixed rendered code.  Once that code is rendered, you need something to operate more dynamically.  Advanced HTML5 will allow for some functionality along these lines, but we're talking high-end development, which will relies on JavaScript.  Maybe with HTML6 we'll see dynamic rendering, but I doubt it.

I hope this additional information helps to clarify why the HTML/CSS option isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u18yduxb/) Change the attribute on hover using jquery and then on hover use `unbind` to disable the hover effect

```js
$('.footer').hover(function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://www.thiefmissions.com/targa/fan.gif");
   $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```

```css
.footer {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="footer" src="images/website footer static.jpg" ;>
```